# Take search term, check for it in database, returning matching term MySQL php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

this seems like such a simple error, but i'm completely stuck. Here is the code:

```
 if (!empty ($_POST['searchbird'])){
        $searchbird=rawurlencode(trim($_POST['searchbird']));
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT `sciname` FROM `wp_birds` WHERE $searchbird = `comname`");
    if (!$result) {
        echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }
    $searchterm = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

the SQL database is setup Col 4 is the comname and col 5 is the sciname

and here is the error
Could not run query: Unknown column 'this is the searchterm' in 'where clause'

Comment: You have your column name and the value you're searching for the wrong way round.

Comment: sql uses % to indentify search terms. did you use these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your current query,

```
SELECT `sciname` FROM `wp_birds` WHERE $searchbird = `comname`
```

if the data type of comName is string, the value should be enclosed with single quotes since they are literals.

```
SELECT `sciname` FROM `wp_birds` WHERE  `comname` = '$searchbird'
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for this mysql injection point, i'll research and stick that in there as well. This solved my problem however, now the $searchterm (after the mysql_fetch_row () variable is returning 'array' not the searched for term.

Comment: it returns a resource which you need to iterate, see here how, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

Comment: thank you so much for the help, I have so much to learn!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **you are exposing yourself to [SQL injection](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/sql-injection-example/)**. Before doing anything else, you will need to cover this. The [PDO library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) makes it very easy and safe.

Regarding your question, the final query is the following:

> SELECT `sciname` FROM `wp_birds` WHERE this is the searchterm = 'comname'

What you are looking for is the following (note the quotation marks):

> SELECT `sciname` FROM `wp_birds` WHERE comname = 'this is the searchterm'

**But you should not do that**, because you are still exposed to SQL injection.